# I'm working on keystroke dynamics project and getting this error

Tags: python-3.7

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "N:\NCI Cyber Security\Sem 3\keycalculatingValue.py", line 37, in 
finalData['key'] = chr(keyList[j])
TypeError: integer argument expected, got float

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without seeing more code, but it looks like `keyList[j]` is returning a float while the function chr() requires and integer in the range 0 through 1,114,111. If the integer is out of that range it will return a ValueError; it seems if the input type is incorrect it will return a TypeError, although that does not seem to be documented.

The following code gives the same error:

```
(j := 1.0) and chr(j)
```

Comment: can i share a code with you?

Comment: can you could the question with producible example? i'd concentrate on how you're constructing keyList, and if you are using `ord` to read the key stoke whether you perform any operation on the result before adding it to the list.